# sometime only some portion of audio play in IE9 and above version

Tags: javascript, html

I have a eBook with audio and highlighting sync. It is working fine in chrome and mozile. But there is a problem in IE which occur sometime. 
The problem is :- 
In IE some audio play only some portion and stops. when I refresh it then it play again but I don't want it to occur this type of problem.